# Passing non-integer value with GET method

Tags: php, javascript, get

I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi');
    alert(<?php echo($_GET['ID'])?>);
});
```

When I have a url like  url/?ID=222 everything works as I'd expect.  When ID has a non-integer in it, url/?ID=222ff, the program crashes(no alerts)..What is going on here?

Comment: Beware of introducing an XSS vulnerability with that.

Comment: I believe I'm protected from sql injection, I use PDO when querying the database.  How does this allow for xss attacks?

Comment: `http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=");</script><script src="mystuff.js"></script>` (encoded, of course) or something to that effect

Comment: is that a reflected XSS?  can I protect against that by escaping and removing tags from the GET value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always wrap the value in quotes if you're not sure of the data type:

```
alert("<?php echo($_GET['ID'])?>");
```

Note, the value returned from `echo` shouldn't contain unescaped quotes, otherwise it would raise a syntax error.

Comment: @JoseCalderon; "okay... Thanks." That is it??? If answer helped you then you need to accept the answer. This is SO rule I think...

Comment: SO doesn't let you confirm an answer until 15 mins has passed after you post a question...simmer down.